# How to make a chart like this from pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas

DISCLAIMER: Can't share the df because it's on work pc.

So I have 3 columns, the first one is just text, the 2. and 3. contain numbers. I want to create a chart where the 2. and 3. columns are displayed next to each other as bar, and the amount of rows I want to display is a variable, so I could change it to 5 or 10 or whatever I need, is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

convert text column to index, filter top rows by [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and ploting by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abc'),
                   'b':range(3),
                   'c':[4,8,3]})
    
N = 2
df.set_index('a').head(N).plot.bar()
```